# C++: How do I round arithmetically after a division with BASIC operations?

Tags: c++

I just started learning how to program in C++ and I'm already desperate because of one task. I'm only allowed to use the following operations: + - * / % and brackets and int variables and declaration, e.g. a = b;

The task is to divide int numbers a and b. The output should be the mathematically / arithmetically correct rounding to the next int. How do I do that? I can't use if/else, define new functions etc. I really don't know and I've tried a couple of things but they don't work for every case (a and b can be all positive integers).

Thanks a lot for your help!!!!

EDIT: As we didn't learn what bool etc. is, I can't use it. It should output, for example 5/2 = 3 (rounded up)
7/3 = 2 (rounded down)

Comment: Please show your code. What did you try? Why did it not work?

Comment: So `5 / 2` and `6 / 2` should both produce `3`, correct?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are allowed to do, but my idea is to convert the remainder to `bool`

Comment: `int res = (int) ((double)a/b + 0.5);`

Comment: We don't have bool yet, so I cant use it ;(

  c = (a+(b-1))/b;
  
  

  std::cout << c;

Comment: @Ripi2 this could easily fail: 10/3

Comment: Why is `5 / 2` rounded up while `7 / 2` rounded down?  That doesn't make any sense

Comment: Rounding halfway to odd is very uncommon, do you actually mean `5/2 == 2` and `7/2 == 4` ("Bankers' rounding")? Also, do you care about possible overflow of large integers?

Comment: Sorry, 7/3 = 2.33 , should round down to 2. I'm already so tired that I can't calculate any more...

Comment: So they are not "rounding to the next int", but round to the closest?

Comment: Please clarify which operations should round up and which should round down.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want to round to nearest, and that `.5` goes to the next bigger integer. And we restrict to `a > 0` and `b > 0`.

Consider that you already get the correct answer for half of the cases from simple integer arithmetics (because it is always rounding down). To get also the other half correct, you can shift the numerator by half the denominator:

```
#include <iostream>

int divide(int a, int b){
    return (a+b/2) / b;
}

void test(int a, int b){
    std::cout << a << " / " << b  << " = " << (double)a/b << " == " << divide(a,b) << "\n";
}

int main(){
    for (int i=0;i<20;++i){
        test(i,3);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
0 / 3 = 0 == 0
1 / 3 = 0.333333 == 0
2 / 3 = 0.666667 == 1
3 / 3 = 1 == 1
4 / 3 = 1.33333 == 1
5 / 3 = 1.66667 == 2
6 / 3 = 2 == 2
7 / 3 = 2.33333 == 2
8 / 3 = 2.66667 == 3
9 / 3 = 3 == 3
10 / 3 = 3.33333 == 3
11 / 3 = 3.66667 == 4
12 / 3 = 4 == 4
13 / 3 = 4.33333 == 4
14 / 3 = 4.66667 == 5
15 / 3 = 5 == 5
16 / 3 = 5.33333 == 5
17 / 3 = 5.66667 == 6
18 / 3 = 6 == 6
19 / 3 = 6.33333 == 6
```

I will try to visualize what happens here, actually it is rather simple:

For denomiator 3:

```
a          0   1   2   3   4   5   6  
a/3        000000000   111111111   222222    <- integer arithmetics
round(a/3) 00000   111111111   2222222222    <- desired result
a/3==n.5         ^           ^
```

For denominator b

```
a          0   1   2  ... b/2   ...   b-1   b   b+1    
a/b        000000000000000000000000000000   111111111111   
round(a/3) 000000000000   111111111111111111111111111111
a/b==n.5                  ^
```

With denominator `b=3` we need to add an offset of `1` to `a` to get correct results. In general we need to add an offset of `b/2`. I hope the tables speak more than words.

Note that `a+b/2` is suspectible to overflows. There are other mathematically equivalent epxressions that do not overflow that easily. As the final result for sure fits in an `int` we can use `unsigned` for the intermediate addition:

```
int div = (static_cast<unsigned>(a) + static_cast<unsigned>(b/2)) / b;
```

For typical implementations where `unsigned` can store the sum of any two positive `int`s this avoids the overflow.

Comment: @kp00 please look at the code more carefully. The solution is `(a+b/2) / b;` thats all. The rest of the code is only to produce the output

Comment: @kp00 if there is something in the code that you do not understand please ask so I can clarify

Comment: Thank you a lot. It worked! You saved my day! Could you please explain why it worked?

Comment: `a+b/2` could overflow. If all inputs are positive `(a-b/2)/b+1` should be fine.

Comment: @kp00 I can try to explain but it will take a while

Comment: `(a+b/2) / b` can overflow and may  also be incorrect  with negative operands.  @chtz `(a-b/2)/b+1` has similar problems.

Comment: I would love if you could explain... btw I study maths...

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica a and b are positive

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica but yes, I should have mentioned it in the answer also

Comment: @chtz Fair enough.

Comment: @chtz Try `a=1, b= 100` with `(a-b/2)/b+1`.  I get 1, is not 0 expected?  `a/b + (a%b + b/2)/b` might handle all `0 < a,b <= INT_MAX` without overflow but is ponderous.

Comment: @chux, you are right (regarding the `a<b` cases). But `a%b + b/2` still overflows, e.g., for `a=INT_MAX-1`, `b=INT_MAX`.

Comment: @chtz  Yes, a better approach is to take my own advice and form a [test harness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64029982/2410359).

Comment: @chtz is it possible to avoid the overflow by doing the intermediate addition with `unsigned`s? The final result for sure fits in an `int`

Comment: @idclev463035818 `unsigned` range overwhelmingly is about twice the positive range of `int` and well handles overflow concerns here and is a reasonable idea. e.g. (change `2` to `2u`).  By C spec, `UINT_MAX == INT_MAX` (same positive range), is possible, yet is rare if ever seen these days.